# Change default picture - registration flow - AZURE - ADB2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

In the ADB2C user registration flow you have an picture on the left & the form on the right. Is there an easy way to change the picture on the left? I don't want to redesign the whole page.

Answer (score 3):

Full customization which includes your own HTML/CSS is available for all the Azure AD B2C user flows including the "sign-up or sign-in policies"  which offers a combined - registration and login - policy.

The "sign-in" policy type is the only one that offers the ability to customize via the "company branding" feature which needs only a picture upload. 
[image]

All other flows require upload of HTML/CSS content. A template is available.  Full customization is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization

Page UI Customization is under Policy->Edit policy->Page UI Customization->Select page->provide source URI
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

How you get to Company Branding has changed, see [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49578162/185123).

---

**Previous**

Yes.  Go to `Users and Groups -> Company Branding -> Edit -> Sign-in page background image`.

I couldn't find an official documentation on [learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview) to reference, unfortunately.

[image: user and groups link]

[image: company branding -> edit]

[image: set background pic]

[image: sample]

Comment: Thanks you very much for the answer. Unfortunately this doesn't answer my question. I know that the login flow is like this. I wanted it for the registration flow.

Comment: np @JohnFinch.  It **should apply** to all policies.  It is only working on my edit policy though.  I'm going to open another SO question for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058810/b2c-company-branding-not-applying-to-all-policies