# B2C Company Branding Not Applying to All Policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've uploaded a `sign-in page background image` but it is only applying to my `Edit Policy`.  Shouldn't it apply to all policies*?

[image: company branding customization]

Works on Edit Policy

[image: Works on Edit Policy]

Not working on my Sing-Up Policy

[image: Not working on my Sing-Up Policy]

*Assuming I haven't assigned a custom page URI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the sign-in policy and the "sign-in" page of profile edit policies use the mechanism that you have highlighted in your question. All other pages in all B2C policies have their own customization, which is described in another question by Jose Rojas: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46057178/3728123.

Comment: thanks @Omer Iqbal.  I had just posted this and when I refreshed the related issue that answer was now there