# Azure AD B2C Page UI Customization without Signup

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

My web app doesn't need `signup` feature. So i am only looking for `signin`. So i didn't setup anything under `signup or sign policies`.

I am trying to add custom login page to `signin policy` in Azure AD B2C. I selected `Local Account SignIn` as Identity provider. But the option `Page UI Customization` is not enabled and a lock symbol is shown. There is no validation message or information or tooltip explaining what should i do to unlock this feature.  But this feature is enabled under `signup or sign policies` blade.

Can somebody help me with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change default picture - registration flow - AZURE - ADB2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037815/change-default-picture-registration-flow-azure-adb2c)

Comment: Alternatively, can you use the sign-up or sign-in policy, and then hide the "div.create" element by your custom CSS?

Answer (score 2):

As stated on the [UI customization docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization), sign-in pages (in sign-in and profile edit policies) can only be customized using the [company branding feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-add-company-branding). The question that spottedmahn linked to in the comments (about [changing default picture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037815/change-default-picture-registration-flow-azure-adb2c)) provides some useful steps.

UPDATE #2: I am retracting my update of "hiding" the link on sign-up/sign-in. That's because if you just hide the link, a user can still make a call to the signup endpoint directly and create a user account. This is not possible through sign-in policy.

Comment: If you'll willing to use custom policies, you can [disable the sign-up portion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47292962/185123) in the policy, therefore, addressing UPDATE #2.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the "Sign-up or sign-in" policy for this, and provide a custom template with you own CSS that hides the sign up link:

```
.create{
    display: none
}
```

'create' is the name of the CSS class used for the signup link.