# Can I disable sign-up in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Can I disable sign-up in Azure AD B2C? In other words, I don't want customers to sign up accounts by themselves, I want it to be done only by admin in Azure. Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Built-in Policies**

Yes, only define a [Sign-in policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-sign-in-policy).

Do not define a [Sign-up or Sign-in policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-sign-up-or-sign-in-policy) nor a [Sign-up policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-sign-up-policy).

---

**Custom Policies**

The problem with a sign-in only policy is you only have basic UI customization options.  You do not get the full set of features as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization).

With custom policies, you can define a Sign-Up/Sign-In policy and then disable the Sign-Up portion.  This allows for the same level if UI customization as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization).

1. Hide the Sign-Up link via CSS
2. Remove `<Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonUsernameExchange</Item>` from your TechnicalProfile

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Username-NoSignUp">
    <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
        <!-- Want to disable sign-up on unified policy -->
        <!-- <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonUsernameExchange</Item> -->
        <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Username</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted-ext-local</Item>
        <Item Key="language.button_continue">Login</Item>
    </Metadata>
    ...
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: Is it safe to just 'hide' a link via CSS? Wouldn't it be possible to display it with some tinkering in console view?

Comment: No, it wouldn’t be safe by itself which is why the custom policy change is needed. @Cedric

Comment: AAD B2C is an unmitigated disaster... I can't believe the number of hacky workarounds one has to perform just to get simple, basic functionality working. It's really quite shocking.

Comment: Years later... There's a "SignIn (Standard)" policy that works as stated in this answer (without UI customization) and a "SignIn (Recommended)" policy that does have same UI customization as SignUpIn.

Answer (score 27):

In **Built-in policies** (aka User Flows) you can choose a sign-in only policy.

In **Custom Policies** you can use the metadata properties shown in the snippet below, *without defining any custom css*.

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
  <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <!-- Clear SignUpTarget for security reasons -->
    <Item Key="SignUpTarget"></Item>
    <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
    <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
    <!-- Remove signup and forgot password links -->
    <Item Key="setting.showSignupLink">false</Item>
    <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkLocation">None</Item>
  </Metadata>
  ...
</TechnicalProfile>
```