# How can I get a forgot password link on a custom Sign In policy for local accounts?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

Using AAD B2C identity experience framework, I am trying to create a custom policy that allows sign-in to a local AADB2C account and includes a "Can’t access your account?" link invoking the built-in self-service functionality.  So basically I want the user experience/functionality of the built-in "B2C_1_SignIn_Local" policy, but as part of my suite of custom policies.  I do NOT want this userjourney/experience to allow the user to choose a different IdP.

I have been able to create a userjourney that invokes a local sign-in, but the UI doesn't include the  "Can’t access your account?" link.  The userjourney I have so far looks like this:

```
 <UserJourney Id="SignInB2CLocal">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignInWithLogonNameExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
        </OrchestrationStep>

       <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
        <ClaimsExchanges>
          <ClaimsExchange Id="SignInWithLogonNameExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
        </ClaimsExchanges>
       </OrchestrationStep>


        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>


        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </UserJourney>
```

The above is based on a combination of what I found in the built-in policy B2C_1_SignIn_Local (downloaded file) and what I used for other IdPs like AAD.  I also tried directly calling the built-in B2C_1_SignIn_Local from my MVC ASP.NET application but got token validation errors.

Is my intended result possible?

thanks!

Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

(i) Change from the `ClaimsProviderSelection` and `ClaimsExchange` orchestration steps to the `CombinedSignInAndSignUp` one with the `api.signuporsignin` content definition, or

(ii) Change from the `api.selfasserted` content definition to the `api.signuporsignin` one for the `SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email` technical profile.

What is important is the `<DataUri />` value for the content definition is set to:

```
urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:unifiedssp:1.0.0
```

which renders the "Forgot your password" and "Sign up now" links.

**i) The `CombinedSignInAndSignUp` orchestration step**

```xml
<OrchestrationSteps>
  <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signupsignin">
    <ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
    </ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
      <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
  </OrchestrationStep>
  <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <Preconditions>
      <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
        <Value>objectId</Value>
        <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
      </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
      <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
  </OrchestrationStep>
  <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <ClaimsExchanges>
      <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
  </OrchestrationStep>
  <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
</OrchestrationSteps>
```

**ii) The `LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange` technical profile**

```xml
<TechnicalProfiles>
  <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.signuporsignin</Item>
    </Metadata>
  </TechnicalProfile>
</TechnicalProfiles>

<OrchestrationSteps>
  <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <ClaimsExchanges>
      <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
  </OrchestrationStep>
  <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <Preconditions>
      <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
        <Value>objectId</Value>
        <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
      </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
      <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
  </OrchestrationStep>
  <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <ClaimsExchanges>
      <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
  </OrchestrationStep>
  <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
</OrchestrationSteps>
```

Comment: What if I don't want the "Sign up now" link?

Comment: You have to hide it using a CSS style: `div.create { display: none; }`

Comment: @MHerbener - [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47292962/185123) might help.

Comment: Got this working once I figured out how to make my customization file work in general.  I did also choose to hide the "OR" (which introduces the sign-up block) with `div.divider {  display: none;  }`.  Thanks!

Comment: @MHerbener better way to hide it is to add Metadata Item to the technical profile: 
`<Item Key="setting.showSignupLink">false</Item>`

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but I am pretty sure you change:

```
ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.idpselections"
```

To:

```
ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignin"
```

This should just show the local account sign in page with no registration and the password reset.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the MS-provided set of starter configuration files do not included a contentdefinition for api.localaccountsignin, even though it is listed (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-ui-customization-custom) as a legitimate Content Definition ID.  But thanks for responding!