# B2C Sign-in only by using Azure AD account

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I am implementing Sign in by using Azure AD accounts scenario, described here - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom

I understand how to change custom policy in file SignUpOrSignIn.xml, but I don't want users to sign up freely into my application.
I want to use sign-in only policy, but there are no sign-in only policies files in the starter pack.

Is it possible to have Azure AD login button on sign-in only screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove everything related to sign-up and any other user journey you don't want, from a combined policy.

Comment: Thanks. Will it also remove **Don't have an account?Sign up now** link from that screen?

Comment: No, but you can use CSS to hide those elements.

Comment: And if you want more information, take a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47292082/can-i-disable-sign-up-in-azure-ad-b2c/47292962#47292962