# Why is my default Azure AD B2C sign-in page showing no labels?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Steps to recreate:

- Create a new Azure AD B2C https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/trial/get-started-active-directory-b2c/
- Set up a sign-in policy with all the default options
- Select "Run Now" in the new policy

Result:

The screen below appears.

Expected:

The screen shows labels on the email and password boxes.

[image]

Comment: Woah.. Looks like a bug in B2C. Did you try again a moment later?

Comment: Tried it on multiple browsers, created a new, default AD B2C for testing, and seeing same behaviour everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the upvoted answer on this: [Azure AD B2C Page UI Customization without Signup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46604209/azure-ad-b2c-page-ui-customization-without-signup/46661719#46661719)

Basically, you need to use the company branding feature for this particular policy. You can add labels through this feature.

Comment: OK, so having a sign-in only policy is no longer supported?

Comment: From that upvoted answer:

> UPDATE #2: I am retracting my update of "hiding" the link on sign-up/sign-in. That's because if you just hide the link, a user can still make a call to the signup endpoint directly and create a user account. This is not possible through sign-in policy.

Comment: I want to avoid end users creating an account.