# Azure AD B2C lefthand sidebar doesn't have "Company Branding" tab

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I would like to change the Azure AD B2C default sign-in picture using the steps listed in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46056063/9268003).

However, when I log into the Azure Portal and find my instance of Azure AD B2C, and click into it, I see the following lefthand sidebar, which doesn't include the "Users and Groups" tab under the "Manage" section, but only includes the "Users" tab (which, if clicking into it, doesn't have "Company Branding" tab inside).

[image]

**How can I find the "Company Branding" tab? Do I have to upgrade my subscription or something to have access to it?**

(Also, one difference I noticed between the screenshots in the SO answer linked above and the screenshot I provided is that the link's Azure AD B2C instance name is `spottedmahnb2c.onmicrosoft.com`; the name of my instance is `login.mydomain.com`. Potentially this points to the difference.)

---

**UPDATE**

It seems that there is no "Basic" vs "Premium" subscription for Azure AD B2C. However, I am adding a bit more information.

[This is the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization) that describes how to modify the login UI for AADB2C. However, when clicking on [the "Company Branding" link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/customize-branding), it takes me to an AAD page. **Does that mean in order to customize the login UI for AADB2C, I have to visit AAD's "Company Branding" page?**

Comment: Yes.  Company Branding is only accessible via the AAD "Company Branding" menu blade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an Azure AD B2C tenant, you have access to two (2) different menus for tenant admin.

- Azure AD B2C
- **Azure Active Directory**

The **second one** has the access to Users and Groups and Company Branding.

In the portal.azure.com, upper right, within the context of your b2c tenant, select **All services** then search for "b2c" or for "Active Directory" to find select the menu blade.

The "Company Branding" option is useful ONLY for the b2c sign-in journey/policy.  All other policy types are customized following this guide: [Azure Active Directory B2C: Customize the Azure AD B2C user interface (UI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization).

Comment: Interesting, it wasn't this way in the past.  [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46056063/185123).  Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1):

1. From within your B2C Tenant

   [image: directory screenshot]
2. Go to Azure Active Directory

   [image: active directory screenshot]
3. Select Company Branding -> Edit

   [image: company branding screenshot]

**Note:** The company branding link was under B2C -> All users previously.  [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46056063/185123).

**Previous**

Missing for me too.  Must be an issue in Azure.  [Azure Support on Twitter](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport) could probably help.

[image]

Comment: Do you have Basic or Premium subscription?

Comment: Didn't know there was such a thing.  Do you have a link?  [Reference](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory-b2c/) @Emilia

Comment: I don't @spottedmahn. The Azure Twitter folks were asking me. :)