# Azure ADB2C Company Branding Image not able to choose in userflows

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am new to Azure ADB2C, my intention is to create adb2c tenant and webapps and create user flows my App service application. I will be using custom html for my signin flow, but for password reset flow I want to use default page from azure but to overwrite default image shown on left and show my company branding images/logo's. I uploaded images and logos under Azure Active Directory ->  Company Branding. But I can't see any option to use uploaded images in my user flows or page layouts. I referred this post ([Change default picture - registration flow - AZURE - ADB2C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037815/change-default-picture-registration-flow-azure-adb2c/46056063) ), for them the image has updated automatically but for me am still seeing default image from azure in password reset page. I am using Free Trial subscription from MS now to do the POC, does it make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for them the image has updated automatically but for me am still
>   seeing default image from azure in password reset page

The "sign-in" policy type is the **only one** that offers the ability to customize via the "company branding" feature which needs only a picture upload. So you will not see any change in password reset page.

If you want to overwrite default image for password reset flow, you need to customize the html. You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview

Comment: ok thanks Tony Ju, I will try to create custom html page and ask you for any issues

Comment: @VigneshwaranKS Sure. If my answer is helpful for you, please make it as answer. Thank you. And if you have any further issue regarding this, just let me know.

Comment: @VigneshwaranKS Do you have any other concerns regarding my answer?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I am using own custom html page for my user flows. I am using react js adb2c libraries in my application. In signup and signin v2 userflow, there is an option to reset password link but the link doesn't take me to my password reset user flow. Error in console: access_denied:AADB2C90118: The user has forgotten their password. I am not getting any samples in react js to solve this issue. This error thrown from react-azure-adb2c library. Any suggestion will be great.

Comment: @VigneshwaranKS Thanks for your update. Can you just accept this answer and  post a new question? This will be beneficial for others to refer to in the future.

Comment: Where can i find option to accept as answer? I can't find in this page.

Comment: @VigneshwaranKS To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: posted my new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55918135/link-user-flows-in-react-js-application